# Is there a cheat to disable police wanted levels?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, cheats

I don't need a 'lower police level' cheat, I need a way of stopping my wanted level from rising at all - a 'no Police' cheat.

Is there a 'No Police' cheat for PS3?

Answer (score 6):

You can disable it by going to Trevor's hunting mission (Fair game). While on the mission, you can do anything without a wanted level. And you can go back to the city if you'd like, after you start the mission.

Comment: The mission is called Fair Game.   I confirmed it works. I even entered the base and took a tank. soldiers didn't do anything.   however, the traffic becomes too little

Comment: also it seems better to do it after reaching the point where it says photograph the elk.   otherwise any big noise you make even far away it causes mission failed, elk heard trevor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such cheat. A full list of cheats can be found here: http://gta.wikia.com/Cheats_in_GTA_V#PS3

The lower wanted level cheat is on there but there's nothing that permanently disables them.